# Get cookie within an Ajax API post request - Laravel 5.6

Tags: ajax, cookies, laravel-5.6

After running an API call, in my controller, I'm trying to get the cookie value like this:

```
 Cookie::get('gtdk')
```

It returns a empty value, although the cookie was already set in the browser.

Do I need to pass the cookie value as a parameter in the ajax call?

**EDIT**
It is also happening in a WEB route call - the cookie is not there when trying to read it in the Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so laravel encrypts the cookie names.

As the cookie was set using Javascript in the frontend, I could not read it by using Laravel methods.

Therefore, I've used it using PHP standard:

```
$_COOKIE['gtdk']
```

Another option is adding an exception for that cookie name in the the middleware.